# Constructing a Bijective function via an injective and surjective one.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $\;f_1,\;f_2:\;A\to B$ such that $f_1$ is injective and $f_2$ is surjective.

I was trying to find out whether there exists $f_3:\;A\to B$ such that $f_3$ is bijective. Is it possible to construct it from $f_1$ and $f_2$?

I tried proving the statement non-constructively via a cardinality argument, but ended up hand-waving a lot (i.e., since the cardinality is the same, there exists a bijection, a bit of circular reasoning). But, I'd be more interested in a construction based argument, as I can't think of one.

Comment: Can we assume choice?

Comment: @Holo I don't see why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim 1: In ZFC $f:A\to B$ surjective implies there exists [right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses).

Proof: Let $\forall x\in B(C_x=\{y\in A\mid f(y)=x\})$ and define $C$ the collection of all $C_x$.

Because $f$ is a function we have $\bigcup C=A$, and also $x\ne y\implies C_x\cap C_y=\emptyset$. Now let $h$
 be a choice function $h:C\to\bigcup C$, lastly we will define $g:B\to A,g(x)=h(C_x)$.

Now, $f(g(x))=f(h(C_x))=f(y)=x$

Claim 2: the right inverse is injective.

Proof: let $x\ne y$ then $C_x\cap C_y=\emptyset$, if so $h(C_x)\ne h(C_y)\implies g(x)\ne g(y)$.

---

Now using Schröder Bernstein theorem on $f_1$ and the right inverse of $f_2$ you get $|A|=|B|$ thus there exists bijective $f_3:A\to B$

Comment: Interesting proof! Do you have an idea for a constructive proof? I presume a constructive one wouldn't be able to use AoC since that's what makes this proof non-constructive.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is impossible as there existence of right inverse is **equivalent** to AC(try and prove it), and Asaf gave an example where the existence is false without choice so...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming choice, yes.

The surjection can be reversed, so you have two injections and the Cantor–Bernstein finishes the job.

Note that if $B$ is empty then $A$ is empty, since there is an injection from $A$ to $B$.

Without choice, however, there is an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $[\Bbb R]^\omega$, the set of countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$, and there is a surjection as well (fix a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R^N}$, and then map every sequence to its range, or the natural numbers if the range is finite).

But a theorem of Sierpinski show that if there is a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ then there are sets without the property of Baire and non-measurable sets. Since it is consistent that all sets have the property of Baire, or all sets are Lebesgue measurable, in such models there is no bijection between the two sets.

(There are other examples of this sort, e.g. $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R/Q}$.)

Comment: Oh interesting! Is there a proof for that last assertion?

Comment: I am sure I wrote about it before. I will look for a link once I am on a proper computer.

Comment: I gave up on searching for a link, so I just added the explanation.